# How to fold text to header above in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Q: how do I fold the current org-mode block where my cursor is inside of it?

I want to fold block under the current heading only. I know that I can use `org-hide-block-all` to fold all blocks in the buffer, and `org-hide-block-toggle` to toggle the current block (i.e., the one at point). But how about folding one block under the current heading?

For example:

```
* header 1
  Some text here 
* header 2
  Some text here [point/cursor]
* header 1
  Some text here
```

I'd like to be able to fold the text under header 2 but leave the rests of headers 1 and 3 alone. And if the pointer/cursor happens to be on the header 2 instead of text below, it will also give the same behaviour. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x org-fold-hide-entry`should do it (and you can bind it to a key if you like). `C-h f org-fold-hide-entry` says:

```
Hide the body directly following this heading.
```

That's a bit misleading perhaps: it can be taken to imply that you have to be *on* the heading, but AFAICT it works fine from anywhere in the entry.

EDIT: Here is a toggle function:

```el
  (defun my/org-fold-toggle-entry ()
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (when (org-at-heading-p)
        (org-end-of-line))
      (if (org-fold-folded-p)
          (org-fold-show-entry)
        (org-fold-hide-entry))))
```

BTW, even without a toggle function, you can expand a heading using `org-cycle` (bound to `TAB`), although you may have to move the cursor to the header (e.g. if it is on the ellipsis under which the contents of the entry are hidden). So `C-a TAB` should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it's not the perfect solution because when the entry is folded and the cursor on the header, it doesn't toggle to open. Otherwise it would be perfect. org-toggle-fold doesn't close the entry. So I guess there might be a custom method needed to detect if the header/entry is closed, then open otherwise. Any suggestion?

Comment: I added a toggle function because it was simple enough to do in this case and I had some time available, but note that: 1) you did not *ASK* for a toggle function in your question; you added that requirement in a comment after the answer was provided; 2) you should make the question complete when you ask it, not modify it later (not even in a comment); 3) if you ask a question, somebody answers the question as asked but then you decide that you wanted to ask a different question, instead of modifying the question (which is an absolute no-no) ...

Comment: ... or ask an augmented or plain *different* question in a comment,  please accept the answer to the question as is and *create a new question*, maybe referring to the original question for context.

Comment: You are entirely right, I was perhaps not very clear in my question that I would use the same function for when the cursor is on the header too. I'm very happy with the solution that you have provided as it worked very well for my purproses. I really appreciate your helpful response and thinking in this, thanks for that!